# Changing Date Format on Custom Meta Data w/shortcode call

Tags: php, shortcode, date, formatting

I am currently pulling a date from a users meta and making it so I can input a shortcode and it will show that date in certain places. I have the following code written and it works great!

```
function delivery_date( $atts ) {

global $current_user, $user_login;
      get_currentuserinfo();
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
if ($user_login) 
return $current_user->delivery_date ;

}

add_shortcode( 'delivery_date', 'delivery_date' );
```

Now, my problem is that the date is showing up at Y-m-d (2019-09-25) but I want it to show up as d-m-Y (09-25-2019). What is the best way to do this? What do I need to add to my code and where? All help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with change line to `date('d-m-Y',strtotime($current_user->delivery_date)) ;`

```
function delivery_date( $atts ) {
    global $current_user, $user_login;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
    if ($user_login) 
        return date('d-m-Y',strtotime($current_user->delivery_date)) ;

}
add_shortcode( 'delivery_date', 'delivery_date' );

echo do_shortcode('[delivery_date]');
```

Comment: Yes! You my friend are amazing. I couldn't figure out how to use the strtotime code and where to put it. Thank you!

Comment: your welcome :-)